# Data separation

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a txt file which I want to upload to R, it looks like that:

```
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS1-NOTE1,NOTE2,NOTE3;CLASS2-NOTE1,NOTE2,NOTE3;CLASS3-NOTE1,NOTE2,NOTE3
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS1-NOTE1,NOTE2,NOTE3;CLASS2-NOTE1,NOTE2,NOTE3;CLASS3-NOTE1,NOTE2,NOTE3
```

I want to create a data frame to obtain:

```
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS1 NOTE1
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS1 NOTE2
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS1 NOTE3

NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS2 NOTE1
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS2 NOTE2
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS2 NOTE3

NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS3 NOTE1
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS3 NOTE2
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS3 NOTE3

NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS1 NOTE1
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS1 NOTE2
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS1 NOTE3

NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS2 NOTE1
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS2 NOTE2
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS2 NOTE3

NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS3 NOTE1
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS3 NOTE2
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS3 NOTE3
```

Can someone help me to do this?
I tried with a 'For' loop but every time the variable NAMEOFTHESTUDENT is shifting.

Comment: You can read the file as usual (but with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`) and then after split the strings step by step.

Comment: I did but still changes the students number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use a nested `cSplit` approach:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(
  cSplit(
    cSplit(
      dat, 'V2', sep = ';', direction = 'long'
    ), 
    'V2', sep = '-', direction = 'wide'
  ), 
  'V2_2', sep = ',', direction = 'long'
)
```

which gives:

```
                   V1   V2_1  V2_2
 1: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS1 NOTE1
 2: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS1 NOTE2
 3: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS1 NOTE3
 4: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS2 NOTE1
 5: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS2 NOTE2
 6: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS2 NOTE3
 7: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS3 NOTE1
 8: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS3 NOTE2
 9: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS3 NOTE3
10: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS1 NOTE1
11: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS1 NOTE2
12: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS1 NOTE3
13: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS2 NOTE1
14: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS2 NOTE2
15: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS2 NOTE3
16: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS3 NOTE1
17: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS3 NOTE2
18: NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS3 NOTE3
```

---

**Used data:**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "NAMEOFTHESTUDENT1 CLASS1-NOTE1,NOTE2,NOTE3;CLASS2-NOTE1,NOTE2,NOTE3;CLASS3-NOTE1,NOTE2,NOTE3
NAMEOFTHESTUDENT2 CLASS1-NOTE1,NOTE2,NOTE3;CLASS2-NOTE1,NOTE2,NOTE3;CLASS3-NOTE1,NOTE2,NOTE3", header = FALSE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thank you!